# Populate bootstrapdialog text from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

Having trouble setting the text for my pop-up in codebehind, it will refresh the page, meaning the pop-up disappears.

I tried following an example/tutorial but can't seem to get it to work. I've tried moving the update panel around, and using autopostback = false on the button. I'm sure it's something silly but i just can't see it..

Here is my aspx page;

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" 
CodeBehind="ShowDialog.aspx.vb" Inherits="BootStrapDialog.WebForm1" 
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>
            Hello, world! Hello, world!</h1>
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <asp:Button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" Text="Launch demo modal" OnClick="GenerateModalText" runat="server">

        </asp:Button>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <!-- Modal -->
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label><br />
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                    Modal title</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox><br />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                    Close</button>
                                <%--<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Save changes</button>--%>
                                <asp:Button Text="Save" OnClick="Submit" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And this is my codebehind VB.NET;

```
Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

Protected Sub Submit()

End Sub

Protected Sub GenerateModalText()
    Dim txt As String = "This is sample text genereated from codebehind"
    TextBox1.Text = txt
End Sub



End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Where is your code that shows the modal once you refresh that portion of the page? By default the modal is not shown, so if the page is refreshed obviously it's going to be hidden. To be honest this is going to be a horrible user experience. You're probably going to get flickering. Out of curiousity why are you using webforms and vb.net? There's far better mature things to be using.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan it's what they use where I started working, I know there are better but have to use what they all know. What would you recommend in order to get a cleaner user experience?

Comment: I wonder if you can put the update panel inside the modal, so that the inside is being refreshed instead of the entire container.

Comment: @TheMuffinMan tried putting it inside the modal-content with the same result

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you are dynamically binding the modal you have one of two solutions.

First you can register a startup script to open the modal when the page reloads.

```
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UpdateModal", string.Format("OpenModal(\"{0}\", \"{1}\");", "modal-blank", "static"), true);
```

I have a bit of framework in place to open my modal, but replace the javascript function with the bootstrap modal open code and it should work.

Secondly you can to rebind the modal during the Page_Load event.

Basically, once you push a button the entire page goes through it's lifecycle again before triggering the button event.  If you don't bind the modal the page doesn't know it exists to set the text.